# Javascript add new order id to each new element

Tags: javascript, oop

sorry for my english I really don't now how to correct ask this question!!

I have task list and when I add new task I ned add smomthing like ordinal number to each new task

example task 1 have stored to var whit id 1,Task 2 var id 2 .....
i think i need use iteration but how...?
[Project link](https://jsfiddle.net/wistyleblog/0Ljb4te4/1/)

```
var toDoList = function() {

  var addNewTask = function() {
      var input = document.getElementById("taks-input").value,
        itemTexts = input,
        colA = document.getElementById('task-col-a').children.length,
        colB = document.getElementById('task-col-b').children.length,
        taskBoks = document.createElement("div");

      taskBoks.className = "min-box";

      taskBoks.innerHTML = '<div class="col-3 chack" id=""><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div><div class="col-8 task-text" id="taskContent"><p>' + itemTexts + '</p></div><div class="col-1 color"></div>'

      if (colB > colA) {
        var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-a");
      } else {
        var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-b");
      }
      todolist.appendChild(taskBoks);
    },

    addButton = function() {
      var btn2 = document.getElementById("add-task-box");
      btn2.onclick = addNewTask;
    }

  addButton()
};

toDoList();
```

Comment: I'm new whit javscript can you give me some notes how to fix it please, ore give some example...? i while fix it!! My be i can conntact you and you can give me some advice...?

Comment: ok i while do i whrite now!!!

Comment: i update the js code on jsfiddle, add on stackoverflow

Comment: You want seperate id for each new task?

Comment: Yes the purpose of that is to make priority of task if Id is 1 i goes on top of list!! i dont need add id to html but only store it in var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `id="task_' + (taskCount++) + '"`

```
var toDoList = function() {
  var taskCount = 0

  var addNewTask = function() {
      var input = document.getElementById("taks-input").value,
        itemTexts = input,
        colA = document.getElementById('task-col-a').children.length,
        colB = document.getElementById('task-col-b').children.length,
        taskBoks = document.createElement("div");

      taskBoks.className = "min-box";

      taskBoks.innerHTML = '<div class="col-3 chack" id="task_'+(taskCount ++)+'"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div><div class="col-8 task-text" id="taskContent"><p>' + itemTexts + '</p></div><div class="col-1 color"></div>'

      if (colB > colA) {
        var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-a");
      } else {
        var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-b");
      }
      todolist.appendChild(taskBoks);
    },

    addButton = function() {
      var btn2 = document.getElementById("add-task-box");
      btn2.onclick = addNewTask;
    }

  addButton()
};

toDoList();
```